# Why mysql select results show "#REF!" instead of "NULL"

Tags: mysql, amazon-ec2

I have a server on Amazon-ec2(ubuntu 12 with the miniman resource).
And I develop the stuff at my mac(i7 cpu) and test on another testing server(i5 cpu) which also ubuntu 12.

My problem is: when I execute a long SQL every thing was fine at my mac and testing server(the results of the select data is showing fine, except the execute time is a bit long... at my mac is about 0.04 sec at testing server is about 10 sec).

But when I Execute the same SQL at Amazon-ec2 server on command line it shows "#REF!" not "NULL".(execute time is also incredible long, about 5 mins...)

I have no idea of the key word to search and just search "mysql #REF!" on google and here, still I did not find any answer and clue.

What cause this problem?
And how do I fix it?
Sorry for my poor English and your patient!

Comment: How are you executing your query? What tool?

Comment: Thanks for helping @tadman. 
Command line only.
something ike this: 
mysql -uroot -pblablabla
>>select * from A join B ON A.id=B.id join C ON A.id=C.id

Comment: How did you upload data into your "*Amazon-ec2 server*"?

Comment: I use a backend which made by Zend framework to CRUD the datas in mysql.

Comment: sorry the previous SQL should be left join, not join.
And another things is that "#REF!" only happen on the table which I left join.

Answer (score 0):

Still I didn't find out the real reason about those "#REF!"..
But it **seems like** that I find out the way to avoid it.
I guess the reason is because of the execute time too long.
So at the end, we add the index for the table and now the execute time come down from 5 mins to 0.2 sec.
And those "#REF!" are automatically disappear.